# Solr boost document by friends

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Apache Solr to build a recommendation engine. I want to boost document that are published by the user's friends. How can I implement that?

Comment: What are the fields in your doc?

Comment: hi the doc has following fields: <id> <author> <title> <content> thanks!

Comment: Why don't you implement custom boosting in your code for the result documents after running a search query rather than depending on SOLR to boost documents?

Comment: because if the result is very big? will it all passed to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just incorporate the author term into the search, as a non-required term, something like:

```
+content:whatever author:(friend1 friend2 friend3)
```

This query would require a match on `content:whatever`, and matches on the `author` would boost scoring.  You will probably want to tune the boost level on the author field to suit your needs, particularly if your queries are more complex than a simple term query, as in the above example.